# Optimize PreparedStatements for either one or multiple queries- Java & MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, prepared-statement

If I'm not mistaken, a preparedStatement is destroyed from cache once a connection is closed. At the moment my app is setup so that I have a function to get POJO objects from the database based on the single POJO object passed in. I then have another function to get id's of ALL objects in that table for cases where I need a list, and then in the while loop of that function I get the entire objects one at a time.

However doing this doesn't take advantage of cached queries right? So what is the best way to have a generic getter SQL function that can make use of cached preparedstatements if it is a list of items or a single item? In PHP I can do this easily by checking if the passed in param is an array or not, but Java requires you to define the param object.

So for example, let's say users, here is what I currently have:

```
//Get user object
public User getUser(User user) throws SQLException {
    Connection connection = connectionWrapper.getConnection();
    String query = "SELECT firstName, lastName FROM users WHERE userId = ?";
    PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
    statement.setInt(1, user.getUserId());
    ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery();
    if (rs.next()) {
        //Get database details and set into object
    }
    rs.close();
    statement.close();
    connection.close();
}

//Get all users
public List<User> getAllUsers() throws SQLException {
    List<User> userArr = new ArrayList<User>();

    Connection connection = connectionWrapper.getConnection();
    String query = "SELECT userId FROM users";
    PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
    ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery();
    while (rs.next()) {
        int id = rs.getInt("userId");
        User user = new User(id);
        getUser(user);
        userArr.add(user);
    }
    rs.close();
    statement.close();
    connection.close();
    return userArr;
}
```

It would be nice to be able for the getUser function to handle both an individual object case like above and an array case where an array of user objects (with userId's set) are passed in and it loops through the array to get all objects before closing the connection. Is there a non-messy way to do this or should I just pass a User array to the getUser function in all cases, even if it's just one?

Comment: I am afraid that the idea of "caching" a prepared statement being a bit exaggerated. And you may have way better optimization if put your efforts somewhere else.

Comment: Why the down vote on the question?

Answer (score 1):

If what you're after is performance, then executing 5 queries to find 5 users given an array of 5 IDs is not really the best solution. You'd better execute a single query that loads all the users at once, using

```
select firstName, lastName FROM users WHERE userId in (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

Similarly, your `getAllUsers()` method is extremely inefficient. It should execute a single query, instead of executing a query to get all the IDs, and then a query for every ID found.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but preparedstatements don't work well with the IN clause, and also I wouldn't know how many ID's I'd need to look up, aka I could be looking for all females, all males, all users under age X, which would result in different # of ?'s. I know getAllUsers() is not optimal, but for purposes of OOP and not having to change multiple queries when/if an object changes it has to be done.

Comment: Well, you just have to build a query with as many question marks as there are IDs in your collection or array. You just need a loop. Shouldn't be too hard. If you're not prepared to use JDBC in the right way, don't expect good performances. If you want to avoid writing many similar SQL queries, use an ORM. That's what they're for.

Comment: I'm farily new to Java as a whole, so not rly sure what you mean by using JDBC incorrectly, could you explain how I'm not using JDBC right? Also, I read that I shouldn't loop and concat question marks in a query, hence why I didn't implement it that way, is that not correct?

Comment: Your question shows that you're so concerned about perfroamnce that you care about prepared statement caching. But on the other hand, you're ready to execute 201 queries, each in its own transaction, when a single query could do the same thing, only to avoid some code repetition. That's incoherent. If you want performance, use the best appropriate query. The gain will be much higher than with prepared statement caching. ORMs allow avoiding a whole lot of repetitions implied by the use of JDBC, while still being efficient. Consider using one.